# Authentication sp page

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I want to add one page on my sharepoint site which could be accessed without going through windows authentication login dialog.

Let me know.

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 0):

You will have to enable anonymous access for the Web Application and then set permission for this particular page.

You can also create a [Anonymous Application Page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zwsong/archive/2010/04/29/creating-a-sharepoint-2010-application-page-for-anonymous-access.aspx).